# getline() error in c++ despite defined library?

Tags: c++

i have Array, i want to ask user enter Full name. Getline shows error but i don't know why, i have defined  library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    const int ArSize = 20;
    char name[ArSize];
    char dessert[ArSize];
    cout << "Enter your name:\n";

    getline(cin, name) ;

    cout << "Enter your favorite dessert:\n";
    cin >> dessert;
    cout << "I have some delicious " << dessert;
    cout << " for you, " << name << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: "Getline shows error" can you be more specific please?

Comment: `name` and `dessert` need to be `std::string`s.

Comment: Why are you using character arrays instead of a string?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please including all error messages as verbatim text (screenshots aren't helpful). Also show how you call your compiler.

Comment: I posted a screenshot. I force it to run witohud debugging.

Comment: @GiorgiKhachidze As mentioned screenshots aren't helpful.

Comment: Get the text of the error message from the Output tab.

Answer (score 1):

The global function `getline` expects a `std::string&` as the second parameter, not a null terminated string (or array of `char`). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline.

The member function `std::istream::getline` can work with an array but it needs a second parameter. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline.

You can use either:

```
std::string name;
getline(cin, name) ;
```

or

```
char name[ArSize];
cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

the main reason is: make difference between cin.getline(char*, int) and getline(cin, string).

cin.getline() Extracts characters from the stream as unformatted input and stores them into s as a c-string.
getline is a member function of istream.
your code will look like:

```
cin.getline(name, ArSize);
```

the other version of getline is being a function that takes a string
it is not member of any calss this why we don't use member access operator 
to call it.

```
string name;
getline(cin, name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `cin.getline(name,ArSize);`.

Answer (score 0):

paste this at the top of your code !

```
#include <cstring>
```